# JSON возвращает null

Tags: jquery, json, php, null, javascript

Я отправляю данные на сервер с помощью кода:

```
$("#sendRoute").live('click', function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://test.whirlware.biz/server/",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            timeInMinutes: final_time_m,
            timeInSeconds: final_time_s_rounded,
            averageSpeed: aver_speed_km_h_rounded,
            distance: total_km_rounded
        },

        success: function(data){console.log(data)},
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

Получаю на сервере:

```
<?php
$json_output = array();
$json_output['timeInMinutes'] = $_POST['timeInMinutes'];
$json_output['timeInSeconds'] = $_POST['timeInSeconds'];
$json_output['averageSpeed'] = $_POST['averageSpeed'];
$json_output['distance'] = $_POST['distance']; 

echo json_encode($json_output);
?>
```

Проблема в том что все данные приходят как null, не пойму в чем загвоздка т.к тестировал всё. клиент 100% корректно отправляет данные. В чем может быть проблема?

UPDATE: Просмотрел всё в firebug, запросы отправляются правильно, может ли быть проблема в разных Content-Type-ах?

```
Response Headers
 Connection keep-alive
 Content-Encoding   gzip
 Content-Type   text/html;charset=UTF-8
 Date   Sun, 05 Jan 2014 10:04:33 GMT
 Server nginx
 Transfer-Encoding  chunked
Request Headers
 Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
 Accept-Encoding    gzip, deflate
 Accept-Language    en-US,en;q=0.5
 Content-Length 65
 Content-Type   application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8.
```

`Content-Type` разный, пробовал добавлять `header('Content-Type: text/html');` не помогает, что ещё можно сделать?

To eicto: не могу почему то добавить комментарий. О каких переменных формах вы говорите?

To eicto: я понял о чем вы говорите но у меня нет формы отправки данных, каждое значение считывается с переменной, поэтому я не использую FormData

To vkovalchuk88. Переменные объявлены в другой части кода ранее. Значения у них объявлены, в консоли файрбага JSON выводится корректно т.е данные отправляются, но на сервере почему то null. Пробовал менять кодировку, формат данных, по разному принимать данные на сервере, все равно null.

Comment: на сервере данные пустые в POST или в console.log(data)?

Comment: в логе все корректно: {timeInMinutes: "0", timeInSeconds: "7", averageSpeed: "452.57", distance: "0.88"} а на сервере {"timeInMinutes":null,"timeInSeconds":null,"averageSpeed":null,"distance":null}

Comment: я тут проблем не вижу, но все же на сервере можно добавить проверку на ошибки, это может дать дополнительную информацию к размышлению [json_last_error][1]

[1]: http://il1.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: Пробовал, пишет ошибок нет... Может дело в том как я получаю json, может есть способ получше?

Comment: да, это тоже мысль посмотреть в каком виде данные приходят на сервер прежде, чем начинаете с ними работать.

Comment: а как это можно отследить в php?

Comment: можно сохранить в лог файл $_REQUEST или по отдельности POST, GET и т.п.

Comment: проще в devtools/firebug посмотреть заголовки запроса :)

Comment: спасибо, буду делать

Comment: чет я здесь не вижу переменных форм, я правда на firebug уже пару лет как забил, chrome devtools как-то стабильнее работает

Comment: типа такого:

    Form Data: 
        comment:типа такого:

ещё в пользу моего предположения, что у вас ничего не посылается говорит очень маленький `Content-Length 65` (хотя я не уверен, надо смотреть что именно у вас в Form data)

Comment: Он ничего не посылает, как берутся переменные те что в data?

Answer (score 1):

Сегодня столкнулся с подобной проблемой. Пока решил так:

в js используем для данных encodeURIComponent(s)
в пхп обратно urldecode(s)

полет нормальный